# What is the best way to prevent others from sending false HTTP post request bodies?

Tags: swift, django, heroku, alamofire, moya

I am making a SpriteKit game on Xcode and I'm using Moya to handle networking calls, Heroku to host the database/server, and Django to write the backend code. Right now, game data such as a player's new high score is sent to the server through the post request body in JSON from Moya requests in Xcode. How do I set up a check so that only a legitimate post request from the game app changes the score?

Comment: You can never trust any data from a client.

Comment: @SLaks I dont know much about how CSRF tokens work, but do they prevent stuff like this from happening for forms? Is there anyway I can have a check ?

Comment: No; they just prevent other websites from "stealing" user cookies.

Comment: Anyone can put any data in an HTTP request; it is fundamentally impossible for your app to make a request that no-one can copy or modify.

Comment: @SLaks ah. So how do game creators prevent a user’s highscore in a database from being changed thru a false request?

Comment: There is no foolproof way but you can make it harder by embedding a secret code within the game app.

Comment: some suggestions:
    1. Use https , you can set up letsencrypt for free (https://pypi.org/project/django-letsencrypt/)
    2. Use django auth , so that only request comes from autheticated user is requested (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/)

Comment: @arunp9294: Neither option will help much.